# Is there any way a Unity3D View can be integrated in iMessage Extension App View?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, imessage

There are many tutorials available showing how to integrate a Unity view in iOS app (or a view in general)

https://the-nerd.be/2015/08/20/a-better-way-to-integrate-unity3d-within-a-native-ios-application/

https://the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/

Can someone please guide on how to integrate a Unity view inside an iMessage Extension App?

How do we know what all classes do we have to integrate (make dependency) in an iMessage Extension App from the Unity exported Xcode app?

Comment: I guess you can only integrate Unity app in **your own ios app**. not in someone else's app.

Comment: Thanks Umair. What I meant was iMessage extension of an iOS App. Have updated the description.